# How to debug/solve MemoryError caused by a Pandas DataFame?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas dataframe, say data.

On a laptop which is 32bits and has 2 GB RAM, I am doing this:

```
>>>data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000209 entries, 0 to 1000208
Data columns (total 5 columns):
UserID        1000209 non-null int32
MovieID       1000209 non-null int32
Ratings       1000209 non-null int32
Age           1000209 non-null int32
Occupation    1000209 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(5)
memory usage: 58.7 MB
```

On this dataframe, I am doing RandomForest classification -

```
>>>X = data.drop('Ratings', axis = 1)
>>>y = data['Ratings']

>>>from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>>Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=1)

>>>from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
>>>model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
>>>model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
>>>model.predict(Xtest)
```

But it is throwing following error

```
MemoryError: could not allocate 50331648 bytes
```

I feel like it has something to do with with the specs of laptop I am using but still I don't understand why this is happening. Is there anyway I can tackle this?

Comment: Just to make sure, how much of the 2 GB RAM is actually free? You could have some memory-intense process running, limiting the amount of RAM available for the Python script

Comment: @black_fm Windows Task Manager is showing that some 250-300 Memory is free.

Comment: yeah, that's definitely not enough. I believe python is trying to allocate 50 MB of *continuous* RAM which you probably would not have in this case. Try closing as many application as you can and give it another try. Even better - restart your laptop and do not open anything before running the script.

Comment: In addition to the answer, Always make sure you use 64-bit python

Answer (score 3):

Well the best way is to profiler the memory usage of your script. To do that,

1. Install memory_profiler: `pip install --user memory_profiler`
2. Put all your code into a function to profile it line by line. Something like the following:

   ```
   from memory_profiler import profile

   @profile
   def main_model_training()
       # put all the code in here
   ```
3. Then start the profiling as follows:

   ```
   python -m memory_profiler script_name.py
   ```

---

Here's an example:

Given the following script:

```
from memory_profiler import profile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@profile
def something_to_profile():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
    df.count()

something_to_profile()
```

running the profiling as follows:

```
python -m memory_profiler memory_profiling_test.py
```

Gives the following line by line memory profile:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     5     64.3 MiB     64.3 MiB   @profile
     6                             def something_to_profile():
     7     64.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
     8     64.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       df.count()
```